# Set up existing Magento 2 in Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

I set Magento up using **Cloudways**, and now I'm trying to move it to my local **Ubuntu VM**.
I used the official

> .gitignore from Magento

cloned the project locally, ran composer install, made sure that I had my **env.php** and **config.php** files downloaded and in the right place.

I changed the entire www directory and all its sub dirs to 777

I updated **core_config_data** url's to be the same as the one's I set in sites-available

> **I ran setup:upgrade**

**setup:di:compile**

**indexer:reindex**

**cache:clean**

**cache:flush**

**setup:static -content:deploy -f**

I tried the above in any number of orders. I tried deleting and re-cloning the **repo.**

I sometimes get the white screen of death, and sometimes I see the folder structure, but with no styles applied.

I'm using the Porto theme, and had removed the child theme because it hadn't been set up properly.

Everything works on my live site, but not locally.

I have the most recent database on my local **MySQL**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you
My logs are full of "**broken reference**" warnings

Comment: Check do you have app/.htaccess it's excluded in gitignore. When it's white screen read server error Apache logs for clues.

Comment: I have it. <IfVersion < 2.4>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all denied
</IfVersion>

Comment: If style not applied then check once mode rewrite is working properly ?

Comment: mod rewrite is enabled in apache.

Comment: Is it fine when you switch to developer mode?

Comment: I'm always in developer mode. I suspect that this is an Apache issue, and I've started going down that road, but I'm not all that good with Apache yet, so I'm still on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do 2 things to get it to work:

1: I had to change core_config_data use_secure_adminhtml from 1 to 0 (local dev env, so no security issue), and I had to ease up the permissions so that the static content could generate.

Up and running now